# Align text inside an html table

Tags: css, html-table

I am a CSS newbie, I have a html table as given below

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|Text Sample                    | text                |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|Text Sample Sample             | text                |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to change the alignment of Text1s as below :

```
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|          Text Sample          | text                |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|          Text1  Sample Sample | text                |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

How this be done using CSS?

Comment: What is `text-align:center` for?

Comment: Are you trying to add a fixed margin to the first column, or align column 1 to the right, based on the length of the longest text value in that column?

Comment: @Purpletoucan Not that complicated.

Comment: @Havelock text-align:center doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to indent the first cell of every table row? If so, one way to do it would be like so:

```
tr td:first-child { padding-left: 30px }
```

(or insert your own value)

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to add margin-left for td:first-child

```
// style.css
td:first-child { margin-left: 30px; }
```